# Find line in $\mathbb{R}^4$ going through a point, intersecting with another line and a plane

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to understand how to approach problems of the following sort.

Is there a line in $\mathbb{R}^4$ going through $(2,-1,2,0)$ and intersecting with another line $L=(1,0,2,0)+\text{lin}((1,0,-1,0))$ and the plane $H = \text{lin}((1,0,-1,0),(5,-1,0,-1))$?

It seems basic but no matter what system of equations I set up, it ends up incredibly messy. Is there a straightforward way to tackle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that your point $p$ and your line $L$ are in $\mathbb R^3 := \{ (x,y,z,0) \mid x,y,z \in \mathbb R \}$, so any line will be in $\mathbb R^3$. Now, your plane $H$ intersect $\mathbb R^3$ in the vector $(1,0,-1)$.

So really, the question becomes : Consider $p=(2,-1,2)$ and the two lines $L$ (projected on the 3 first coordinates) and the line $L' = \text{lin}(1,0,-1)$. Is there a line through $p$ which intersect $L$ and $L'$ ?

Let me add more details. For conclude, you need to look at the line $L_t = p + \lambda(2 - t, 1, 2 + t)$. What do you want is to find $t \in \mathbb R$ with $L_t \cap L' \neq 0$. But this is exactly the same to ask that the distance between $L_t$ and $L'$ is zero for some $t$, and there is a [formula here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_lines#Distance) for computing the distance. You only have one cross product and one scalar product to compute.